preciso que ao exporta a tabela para o excel, a celular destacada em verde tambem seja preenchida automaticamente no excel
function downloadExcel() {
  const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);

  // Percorre as células destacadas em verde e cria uma nova folha de Excel
  const newWs = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const newSheetData = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    const newRow = [];
    for (let j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j += 2) {
      const cell = table.rows[i].cells[j];
      if (cell.classList.contains('green-row')) {
        newRow.push({ v: cell.textContent.trim(), s: { fill: { bgColor: { indexed: 0x11 } } } }); // Cor verde
      } else {
        newRow.push('');
      }
    }
    newSheetData.push(newRow);
  }
  const newWsName = 'Destaques em Verde';
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(newWs, XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(newSheetData), newWsName);

  // Exporta a nova folha de Excel com os destaques em verde
  const newWbout = XLSX.write(newWs, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
  saveAs(new Blob([newWbout], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'Destaques_em_Verde.xlsx');
}



  function destacarPrecos() {
  const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  
  // Itera sobre as linhas da tabela
  for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    let menorPreco = Infinity; // Inicializa com um valor alto
    let menorPrecoCellIndex = -1; // Armazena o índice da célula com o menor preço
      
    // Itera sobre as colunas onde os preços estão
    for (let j = 1; j <= 15; j += 2) { // Ajustado para pegar apenas as células de preços
      const preco = parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[j].textContent.trim().replace(',', '.')); // Substituído ',' por '.' para tratar corretamente os números
      if (!isNaN(preco) && preco < menorPreco) {
        menorPreco = preco;
        menorPrecoCellIndex = j; // Atualiza o índice da célula com o menor preço
      }
    }
      
    // Itera novamente para colorir a célula com o menor preço de verde
    for (let j = 1; j <= 15; j += 2) { // Ajustado para pegar apenas as células de preços
      const preco = parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[j].textContent.trim().replace(',', '.')); // Substituído ',' por '.' para tratar corretamente os números
      if (!isNaN(preco) && preco === menorPreco) {
        table.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add('green-row');
      } else {
        table.rows[i].cells[j].classList.remove('green-row');
      }
    }
    
    // Destaca a célula com o menor preço na planilha Excel
    if (menorPrecoCellIndex !== -1) {
      const ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);
      ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: i, c: menorPrecoCellIndex })].s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "00FF00" } } }; // Cor verde
    }
  }
}


Para entender qual a finalidade do dirija-se a [help] e lá explore os links oferecidos.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
